# Regex pattern to find a multiple non-digit characters recurring

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I'm trying to get regex to find matches where in a string of numbers there are more than one instance of a non-digit chracter following each other.

Ie. `0-31-334455(555)` would not be a match, but `0--31-334455()555` would be (twice).

Thus far I have mangled this together: `([\(\)\-\+\s])\1{1,}`, which checks for multiple instances of `() -+` following each other, but it misses `()` for instance.

`([()\\-+ ])\\1` also finds two (or more) of the same character in a row, but it misses `()`.

I'm assuming that something like a not-digit (`\d`) would be easier than defining every character you don't want, but I don't see how to include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a not-digit character class which is `\D`, so just try `\D\D`
See this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xF7iG6/1) for a quick example